# Extract tuple elements in list

Tags: python, tuples

my_tuples = [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), (True, False), 'qwerty'] For this tuple, how can I append all values in list and dictionary. For example, I want output like list1 = [1,2,3,a,b,c] so on and for dictionary I want output like{1:1,2:2,3:3,4:a}.

Thanks in advance.

For list, I tried using length of list but length is different for all tuple elements in list. So I am getting error like index out of range.
I want all elements of list of tuples as single list elements.

Comment: Where does the key `4` in the dictionary come from?

Comment: Make sure to properly format your posts. Here are some tips: Use backticks to `format code`. Use whitespace appropriately – new lines, spaces. Make good use of punctuation.

Comment: In list you wanted `qwerty` like `['qwerty']` or `['q','w','e','r','t','y']`?

Comment: What is the full expected result?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a nested comprehension to iterate first over the tuples in `my_tuples` and then the items in each tuple, putting them into a single list or dictionary:

```
>>> my_tuples = [(1, 2, 3), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), (True, False), 'qwerty']
>>> [i for t in my_tuples for i in t]
[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', True, False, 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y']
>>> {i: v for i, v in enumerate((i for t in my_tuples for i in t), 1)}
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: True, 10: False, 11: 'q', 12: 'w', 13: 'e', 14: 'r', 15: 't', 16: 'y'}
```

Since `'qwerty'` isn't a tuple, it's unpacked into its individual characters (since a string is an iterable of characters, the same way that `(1, 2, 3)` is an iterable of ints).  If that wasn't what you were looking for, you could put it in your list of tuples as `(qwerty,)` to make it a one-element tuple, or you could do it inside the comprehension with an expression like `(t if isinstance(t, tuple) else (t,))`.

Comment: OP need output in dictionary like `{1:1,2:2,3:3,4:a}`..!

Comment: I'm assuming that was a typo in their question and that they meant to write `a:a`, since that would logically follow from the rest of the example.

Comment: assuming if this is not a typo then.. `{idx+1: ele for idx, ele in enumerate(lis)}` after storing elements of tuple in a `lis`.

Comment: There is no typo. I need answer like 1:1,2:2,3:3,4:a

Comment: You could also use `dict(enumerate(itertools.chain(*my_tuples), 1))`